# content jumps to top when setting overflow for DIV

Tags: html, css

How can I fix content to where user scrolled after changing the value of `overflow`?

for example in this fiddle if you scroll down to `SWITCH` and click it, it will jump to top (to hello 1)

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/z25YE/

JavaScript:

```
$('.t').click(function(){
    $('.container').toggleClass('state2');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the class `state2` set height to `200px` and javascript code says to toggle container's class
between 200px and reduces it's default height and as result the scrollbars appear  and the default and it goes to the top of container and it's natural.
to prevent this behavior try this:

```
$(".t").click(function() {
   $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".t").offset().top
   }, 200);
});
```

Comment: Well, any way to prevent this natural behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Content jumps to top because you haven't specified height to the container.  Try giving height to the container as 1200 px ( depending on the height of the browser screen ). This will fix the issue.

Comment: Add height to the body 1500 px